# AS2 - How to remove character after specyfic character

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, actionscript-2

I have  variables like this `AA55BBB(888)1234567890P1`
How to remove characters between `)` and `P`?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd do that with a regular expression but AS2 does not support them. So another (old-fashioned) solution would be split the string on these characters and join it back again

This assumes that you only have one ")" and one "P" in your string:

```
var myString:String = "AA55BBB(888)1234567890P1";

// this will result in an Array like ["AA55BBB(888", "1234567890P1"];
var firstSplit:Array = myString.split(")");

var firstPart:String = firstSplit[0]; // "AA55BBB(888"
var secondPart:String = firstSplit[1]; // "1234567890P1"

var secondSplit:Array = secondPart.split("P"); // ["1234567890","1"]

secondPart = secondSplit[1]; //"1"

// since we have removed the ")" and "P" on split, put them back in
var newString:String = firstPart + ")P" + secondPart;

trace(newString); // "AA55BBB(888)P1"
```

Comment: O soo Coool :) but now it's born new problem. first part of my code it's E123XABCD. This is always the same number of characters How to separate them to become variables

E 123 X AB CD

Comment: If your number and letters are always on the same place it might be easier to work with substr here - it gives you back a part of the string (X characters starting at the startindex). For example, var part:String = firstPart.substr(1,3) will return the part "123", firstPart.substr(5,2) will return "AB". Note that the startIndex starts with a 0 (first character of a string is at position 0)

Comment: It's work Great! I write in my language.
"chodzi zajebiście w ch*j" ;)